# Adding Lots of Subdivisions to a Sphere Without it being rough

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am trying to sculpt on a sphere. But to sculpt you need a lot of subdivisions. The problem with that is it makes the sphere rough and not smooth even when I enable smooth shading and a subdivision surface modifier. How do I get a lot of subdivisions on the sphere without it being rough?

Comment: what do you mean by rough, do you have any images of it?

Comment: Generally for sculpting you don't use Subsurf, rather than Multires instead. And it still would be great to see some screenshots of your mesh to get idea of what does "makes the sphere rough and not smooth" mean.

Comment: Sorry I have been trying to upload an image but it keeps saying it failed

Comment: I mean rough as in it looks like the default non-smooth sphere

Comment: make sure the subdivision modifier is set to use `catmull-clark` and not `simple`.

Comment: If you can't upload any images, try uploading your .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com. Thanks!